# JQuery GET with JSON response. Select specific objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, socrata

I'm working on a simple web app. This will have the client enter a license plate, then connect to a Socrata-based OpenData API which contains the records of all registered cars in my country.

Using the license plate, it must find the correct car, and display specific information. The kind of information displayed will differ, as I intend to use this app on several different web pages, but as a starting point I'd like to display the car's brand and model. These are listed in the array as

```
"merk" : "KIA"
"handelsbenaming" : "PICANTO"
```

Where 'Merk' is the brand/manufacturer and 'handelsbenaming' is the model.

I am not very experienced with javascript, and completely new to JQuery, but I managed to come up with this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var kenteken = "1KBB00";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
$.get("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json",{kenteken: kenteken},function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + " Status: " + status);});
 });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Click</button>
</body>
```

As you can see, the JQuery is fired by pushing the button. I'll make an input field to get the license plate number later on, but in for testing purposes I simply defined the variable "kenteken" to be a real license plate. Also for testing purposes I would like to return the response in an alert box.

On testing, the console in Firefox does not indicate any errors. I can also see the GET request is made, and a JSON array is returned. However, I cannot get the array to write to the document or the alert box. Currently, the alert shows:

```
Data: [object Object] Status: success
```

Whereas, as far as I understand, 'Data' should display the entire JSON array which is returned by the GET request

I used Google, read through the documentation that came with the API multiple times, I've read through more posts on SO than I can keep count of, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: `alert(data.merk);` You can also `console.log(data);` to see, whats in that. Check the console, after you did run the script. (Right click, inspect any element, and find the console)

Comment: 'alert(data.merk);' still returns 'undefined'. 'console.log(data);' gives 'Array [object]'. When I click 'object' it shows the entire JSON array.

Comment: then possible `data[0]['merk']` will be the solution. Please, copy the console, to see the structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is not a single object, it's an array of objects, so you need to index them to access the properties. I show below how to access the first one, but in your real code you would probably loop.

```
$.getJSON("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json",{kenteken: kenteken},function(data, status){
    alert("Merk: " + data[0].merk + " Handelsbenaming: " + data[0]. handelsbenaming + " Status: " + status);});
});
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and your solution worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

when you get your data back it comes as a string.

Turn it back into a JSON object using JSON.Parse(data) and the you should get it to look correctly. Put a breakpoint before your alert and then you can inspect what comes back and what the json method does.

```
$.get("https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json",{kenteken: kenteken},function(data, status){
        debugger;
        var jsonData = JSON.Parse(data);
        alert("Data: " + jsonData + " Status: " + status);});
 });
```

Comment: The console is telling me 'TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function' . Do I need to include an extra library?

Comment: It's `JSON.parse()`. You could also use `$.getJSON` and jQuery will parse it automatically.

Comment: Since he's getting `[Object object]` in his original code, jQuery must be parsing it automatically. It does that if the response has `Content-type: application/json`.

Comment: Using `$.getJSON` resulted in an alert saying `Data: function (a,b,c){return n.get(a,b,c,"json")} Status: success`,      whereas using `JSON.parse(data)` resulted in a console error       `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`

Comment: It looks like jQuery is already parsing the response just fine, so there's no need to re-parse the JSON. Just index into `data` or iterate through it with `$.each(...)`.